# Efficient select on huge table of ranges

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a mysql table which contains the fields: `rangeFrom` and `rangeTo`.

I want to request rows with a condition like: `rangeFrom >= ? AND rangeTo <=?` **within a join**.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT *
FROM Version
JOIN Contract FORCE INDEX FOR JOIN (versionRangeFrom)
  ON Version.id >= Contract.versionRangeFrom
 AND Version.id <= Contract.versionRangeTo
WHERE Version.completedAt = '2016-06-06 10:00:01';
```

Which mysql explains like this:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  Version ref PRIMARY,completedAt completedAt 6   const   1   NULL
1   SIMPLE  Contract    ALL versionRangeFrom    NULL    NULL    NULL    640744  Range checked for each record (index map: 0x8)
```

So it has to work though 640744 rows which takes about 1-2 seconds.

However inserting the version id in the queryworks fine

```
EXPLAIN SELECT *
FROM Contract
WHERE 5 >= Contract.versionRangeFrom AND 5 <= Contract.versionRangeTo;
```

This is then explained like this:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  Contract    range   versionRangeFrom    versionRangeFrom    4   NULL    534 Using index condition; Using where
```

So in this case mysql only goes though 534 rows and that only takes about 30ms.

So how do I prepare for such a range check correctly. It seems that mysql is unable to use Indexes in those cases. I can work around it by using 2 queries but i'd rather have one.

Here more schemas:

```
 CREATE TABLE `Version` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `completedAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `completedAt` (`completedAt`)
) 

CREATE TABLE `Contract` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `contractId` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `startAt` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `endAt` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tradeStartAt` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tradeEndAt` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `latestAiId` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `type` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `daPreis` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lastTradePreis` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lastTradeVol` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `VWAID` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `versionRangeFrom` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `versionRangeTo` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `tradeStartAt` (`tradeStartAt`),
  KEY `contractId` (`contractId`),
  KEY `versionRangeFrom` (`versionRangeFrom`)
)
```

Comment: Please post a schema, and sample queries, ideally with an EXPLAIN. "It seems that MySQL is unable to use indexes" is not really something we can help with.

Comment: @NevilleK done. And I figured that my problem is a little different then I thought and also I found a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

A different value than '5' would not need to look at only 534 rows.

The problem (`x < from AND x > to`)is non-trivial, and for which there is no simple answer.

Shrinking the table size would help a tiny bit.  Don't use `BIGINT` (8 bytes) when some smaller datatype would suffice.

Perhaps the only real solution involves a major revamp of the schema and code.  See [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges).

**Edit**

In *certain* situations, this subquery may be efficiently used to find the row in question:

```
( SELECT Contract.id FROM ...
      WHERE Version.id >= Contract.versionRangeFrom
      ORDER BY versionRangeFrom
      LIMIT 1 )
```

Comment: The Version Range fields are just int (4 Bytes) and they can't be any smaller. But I posted probably to much of my Schema and the other Range there is confusion ;). I tried to build a table with Version to row references. Problem, my Ranges are so big and New versions are so common that the table reached GB in size within minutes (it was still fast tough).

Comment: I see 6 `BIGINTs`.  Please discuss the "version" and the purpose of looking for a range of versions.  Maybe there is some trick that can be performed.

Comment: So this database is a copy of an api which is requested every 3 seconds. Every time I do that I create a new version within a version table (basically just an auto_increment id and a date). Then all new datasets will have there version range set to that new version id. On update I look what has changed and update only the versionRangeTo if necessary. I need these versions because I need to be able to access historical data. There are also long running scripts which must have a consistent set of data while working with it.

Comment: Thanks for the effort so far. So your new query returns one contract, basically the oldest. The problem is: I need all. My current solution is to simply perform 2 queries and that works "good enough" for now.

Comment: If multiple rows can match `5`, the query becomes much more difficult to do efficiently.